# Prove that the number of fractions $a/b$ in lowest terms with $0<a/b \leq 1$ and $b\leq n$ is $\phi(1) + ... + \phi(n)$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ with $n>0$. Prove that the number of fractions $a/b$ in lowest terms with $0<a/b \leq 1$ and $b\leq n$ is $\phi(1) + ... + \phi(n)$.

I'm am not sure how to go about starting this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how it works: $\phi(k)$ counts the number of fractions $\frac{a}k$ in lowest terms on the interval $(0,1]$. Indeed, what does it take for $\frac{a}k$ to be "in lowest terms"? We need that $\gcd(a,k)=1$. Thus, counting the numbers between $0$ and $k$ for which that is true also counts fractions in lowest terms.

Does that help?

Comment: Yes it did, thank  you. Just to make sure I'm on the right track. $\phi(k)$ will count the number of fractions in lowest terms between (0,1] with denominator of $k$. So by summing $\phi(n)$ for $k= 1, 2, ... n$ we count all the reduced fractions between (0,1].

Comment: Yes, all of those with denominators $1,\ldots,n$.